# in matlab i want to get input name for a structure with a field

Tags: matlab, structure

I am trying to read the name of an input but because it is formmatted as a structure and field I am getting nothing back.

Example

```
Y = FnX(struct.field1)


function [Y]=FnX(inputName)

name = %DO SOMETHING%


end
```

Result should be name == 'field1'

Comment: You would **think** from the number of questions posted here and to Mathworks that they'd realize that `inputname` should be able to string-ify `object.substruct`, but nooooo.   I agree it's a glaring deficiency in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inputname()` to get the variable name of function input:

```
function [Y]=FnX(inputName)
name = inputname(1);
end
```

But before calling this, you need to get its field first as `inputname()` doesn't work for structure elements.

```
field1 = struct.field1;
[Y] = FnX(field1); % call here
```

Comment: thanks much, is there a way to do it by sending the struct.field1 directly into function or is this frowned upon?

Comment: @KeithD As far as I know, this can not be done. I have seen lots of discussion, but still not work it through.